# How to create a chart in MVC Having three values to show

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am new in MVC 5, not having much idea about creating chart. 
i need to create a chart which will show the Four values from a table as such below FormatName,Month,SuccessCount, FailCount .
I want to show success and Failcount on the basis of Month for each Format.
Formats are client names. 
I tried with several sites , but no idea how to show the three values.
Month FormatName    SuccessCount    FailedCount 
Jan HPCL    20  32 
Feb FG  23  0     
Mar abcd    13  34 
Apr Test    12  23

Above is the table which i want to show on chart.Unfortunately i cannot add 
 image as it is not permitted yet on stackoverflow. 
I have used below method to show the data  in chart. 
`public List BindFormatByMonth(string status) 
        { 
            DataTable dt1 = new DataTable(); 
            DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
            dt1 = PBMSCommon.Database.ExecuteDataSet("usp_sel_DedupeDetails",
 status).Tables[0]; // success records 
            List ochartmodel = new List();

```
        foreach (DataRow row in dt1.Rows)
        { 
            FormatStatus omodel = new FormatStatus();
            omodel.FormatName = Convert.ToString(row["NVFormatCode"]); 
            omodel.month = Convert.ToString(row["Month"]);
            omodel.successCount = Convert.ToInt32(row["Status"]); 
            ochartmodel.Add(omodel);
        }`
```

any help will be appreciated.

Pooja

Comment: pooja, atleast give us some image. From that we will understand what kind of chart you want and what about your data and all.

Comment: If you elaborate well, you will get good answer from here..

Comment: Hi ,i can provide the link of image .https://www.google.co.in/search?q=chart+types+in+excel&tbm=isch&imgil=2Py0G1Slri2XbM%253A%253BKlKvJ3NyjV56WM%253Bhttps%25253A%25252F%25252Fpeltiertech.com%25252FExcel%25252FChartsHowTo%25252FChartType.html&source=iu&pf=m&fir=2Py0G1Slri2XbM%253A%252CKlKvJ3NyjV56WM%252C_&usg=__adSLphevkPurYrr6E64kpG38anc%3D&biw=1280&bih=614&ved=0ahUKEwiYspnSxbXVAhVGLI8KHSsjCSYQyjcIoAE&ei=9DGAWZjoM8bYvASrxqSwAg#imgrc=tq1i0UFbqEc8YM:

Comment: Give me 20 min, i will come back after a break.  Then i will add an answer

Comment: Google provides several charts and a API to use them. Type "Google charts" on your favorite search engine!

Answer (score 0):

You can use vertical bar chart for your requirement.  I will suggest you to use chart.js. It responsive and user friendly.

So I have added a fiddler here! It would be use full to you!

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p3g07d09/261/)

Html:

```
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

Javascript:

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");

var data = {
  labels: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar"],
  datasets: [{
    label: "HPCL",
    backgroundColor: "skyblue",
    data: [20, 32, 12]
  }, {
    label: "FG ",
    backgroundColor: "maroon",
    data: [23, 10, 15]
  }, {
    label: "abcd",
    backgroundColor: "green",
    data: [13, 34, 16]
  }, {
    label: "test",
    backgroundColor: "violet",
    data: [12, 23, 16]
  }]
};

var myBarChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: data,
  options: {
    barValueSpacing: 20,
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          min: 0,
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p3g07d09/261/)

Comment: Hi @PowerStar, thankyou very much for help, really appreciated. But i cannot add the hard coded values in chart, i need to pass them through database , also i want to create it in razor.

Comment: Yes Pooja, you do your business logic and add it in controller. You do the backend operation first. Then I will help you more.

Comment: If you need steps to do, then tell me. I will suggest.

Comment: hi @Powerstar , i have edited my question and added the code for fetching the data . how can i add the chart into contoller and add these values